# Importing modules from subpackage

Tags: python

My project has this kind of structure:

```
mypackage
|
|-- __init__.py
|
|-- file.py
|
|-- subpackage
    |
    |-- __init__.py
    |
    |-- function.py
```

How do I import the modules in the subpackage from file.py?

I tried a couple of things like simply `import subpackage` or `from subpackage import function` but all of them lead to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage'.

`from . import subpackage` has no error message but I don't know how to access the module with that.

Comment: This should work fine. What is the error message you get when you use `from subpackage import function`

Comment: Regarding how to access, you can do `subpackage.function()` on a separate line to call a specific function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using:

```
from mypackage.subpackage import function
```

Comment: Explicit is always better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```py
from subpackage import function
```

You propably are not in `mypackage` directory

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I type ´from subpackage import function´ in file.py I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage'

Comment: You have to run `file.py` from `mypackage` directory

Comment: For a bit more explicitness, I recommend `from .subpackage import function`